# How to create carousel items based on item count using React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap, mern

How can I loop through an array and based on the item count create new `<Carousel.Item>` and insert a `<Card>` component inside of it.

Let's say I have the following array with some image sources:

```
const items = [
   {
     src: 'http://somerandomimage.com'
   },
   {
     src: 'http://somerandomimage.com'
   },
   {
     src: 'http://somerandomimage.com'
   },
   {
     src: 'http://somerandomimage.com'
   }
]
```

I would like to map through this array and add two `<Card>` per `<Carousel.Item>`
So each `<Carousel.Item>` would look like this:

```
<Carousel.Item>
   <Row>
        <Col lg="3">
           <Card>
               <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.src}/>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      Nisi voluptate ex enim eiusmod pariatur eiusmod non aute 
                      cupidatat cillum pariatur.
                    </Card.Text>
                 </Card.Body>
           </Card>
       </Col>
       <Col lg="3">
           <Card>
               <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.src}/>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      Nisi voluptate ex enim eiusmod pariatur eiusmod non aute 
                      cupidatat cillum pariatur.
                    </Card.Text>
                 </Card.Body>
           </Card>
       </Col>
  </Row>
```

Comment: It looks like you've already solved your own problem: just do `items.map(item => JSX)` where `JSX` is what you wrote above for what you wanted. You only need to add a `key` to each `Carousel.Item` and put that expression inside of braces in your other JSX for everything to work.

Comment: Doing that I'll create a new <Carousel.Item> for each item in the array. I want for every two items in the array create a new <Carousel.Item>. @Prem answer solved my problem.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use array chunk to split that array into smaller chunks.

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function(size) {
  const result = [];

  while (this.length) {
    result.push(this.splice(0, size));
  }

  return result;
};
```

Then map that to render 2 `<Carousel.Item>` with two items in each like below, array chunk will return [[{},{}], [{},{}]]

```
{items.chunk(2).map((chunk, idx) => (
        <Carousel.Item key={idx} className={idx === 0 ? "active" : ""}>
          <Row>
            {chunk.map((item, idx2) => (
              <Col lg="3" key={idx2}>
                <Card>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" style={{width: "50px"}} src={item.src} />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      Nisi voluptate ex enim eiusmod pariatur eiusmod non aute
                      cupidatat cillum pariatur.
                    </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Carousel.Item>
      ))}
```

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-pine-fdtg5?file=/src/App.js